# What's the meaning of "HOW" here?

Tags: word-usage

> 1. I thought about ***how*** if Mike had been along, we wouldn't have talked about a lot of those things,
> 2. You can't help thinking about ***how*** if you could get him off the phone, you might be able to work some sales deals with him
> 3. I think this is a good thing. I know it isn't always. I am pleased that my widowed mother, who can hardly walk now, has the Mets during the season. But I know how bereft she is when the season ends. For Doris baseball was good. For my mother it is both good and bad. For me it is a diversion. But sometimes I think about ***how*** if something really horrible happened to me, it might have to become my life.

Here, what do you mean by ***how*** here?

Is ***how*** the same as ***the fact that***?

Comment: "the fact that" is quite strong, as it implies that you know what would have occurred if the situation had been different.  E.g. in your first example, if Mike had come along, would it be certain that you wouldn't talk about those things?  I would translate that usage of "how" as "the possibility that", as in my experience it is usually used when contemplating other possible outcomes of something.  E.g. I thought about the possibility that if Mike hadn't been along, we wouldn't have talked about a lot of these issues (but might have done so anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much. How about this sentence? "When we were young, I remember how we used to fight all the time". Here, I suppose "how" could mean the reason or the way or the place or something more, depending on the context. So, I think "how" could mean many depending on the context, right? And why we say "how" not "the reason/the way/the place/the fact/the possibility" is because we want some chameleon word like "how", am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right - the use of how really depends on context.  In your second example it means something like "the situations where" or "the times when", e.g. "I remember the situations where we used to fight all the time".  I'm speculating a little here, but I think that people use "how" in the ways we have discussed because its short and easy, rather than saying "the situations where" or "the possibility that", etc.  I think that is why, in my opinion, it is better suited to informal situations and conversational English - I don't recall using "how" in that sense at work!

Comment: Think of the ***if-*** clauses as "parenthetical" (syntactically *optional*) in such contexts. Then it should be a lot easier to parse 1: *I thought about **how we wouldn't have talked about a lot of those things***, 2: *You can't help thinking about **how you might be able to work some sales deals with him***, 3: *I think about **how it might have to become my life***. Where in *some* cases, ***the fact that*** is an obvious "direct replacement" for ***how*** (but in #2 we could *also* understand it as a truly adverbial reference equivalent to ***the way in which,*** or ***the times when***).